# How to extract text between round brackets?

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract the text within () brackets. The string looks like this: It is within the

```
Some text: 5 (some numbers) + some more numbers
asdfkjhsd: 7 (6578) + 57842
djksbcuejk: 4 (421) + 354
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
var fspno = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[142].innerText;
var allfsp = fspno.match();
```

I want this script to collect all numbers within the brackets in an array. I used

```
fspno.match(/\((.*?)\)/g);
```

but it returned with the brackets. I want only the text inside the brackets.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way in javascript to extract all matches with all groups at once, therefore you either have to use `exec` in a loop:

```
re = /\((.+?)\)/g
found = []
while(r = re.exec(fspno))
    found.push(r[1])
```

or abuse `String.replace` to collect the matches:

```
re = /\((.+?)\)/g
found = []
fspno.replace(re, function($0, $1) { found.push($1)})
```

In your particular case, however, it's possible to rewrite the expression so that it doesn't contain groups and can be used with `String.match`:

```
re = /[^()]+(?=\))/g
found = fspno.match(re)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\((.*?)\)/.exec( '7 (6578) + 57842' )[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to turn off the `g` option and get the `[1]` index on the match, e.g.:

```
fspno.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1];
```

But that will return an error if nothing is found, so if you don't know if you'll have a parenthesized part or not, or you can use this idiom:

```
(fspno.match(/\((.*?)\)/) || [,""])[1];
```

which will return `""` if it can't find a match.

If you know you need the `g` option (i.e. there might be more than one thing in parentheses and you want them all) you can use:

```
var match, matches=[]; while (match = /\((.*?)\)/g.exec(s)) matches.push(match[1]);
// matches is now an array of all your matches (without parentheses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not need `g` option. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SYqhu/)

or

```
var fspno = "7 (6578) + 57842";
var found = fspno.match(/\((.*?)\)/);

if (found) {
    var found1 = found[1];
    alert(found1);
}
```